# Obtain all possible combinations of the elements of an array with each other, in pairs and without repeating

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I need to make a function (probably recursive) that given one array gives me another with all possible combinations of couples. For example:

```
Input
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

```
Output
[
    [
        [A, B], [C, D], [E]
    ],
    [
        [A, B], [C, E], [D]
    ],
    [
        [A, B], [D, E], [C]
    ],
    [
        [A, C], [B, D], [E]
    ],
    [
        [A, C], [B, E], [D]
    ],
    //...
    [
        [A, E], [B, C], [D]
    ],
    [
        [A, E], [B, D], [C]
    ],
    [
        [A, E], [C, D], [B]
    ],
    //...
    [
        [B, C], [D, E], [A]
    ],
    //...
    [
        [C, D], [B, E], [A]
    ]
]
```

The idea is to obtain in each result different combinations of the elements without repeating the same pairs that have already been used in previous combinations and without leaving any option without contemplating.

All the questions I saw on stackoverflow are similar but it is not exactly what I am looking for. I tried for 4 hours to solve the code by myself but I give up (At least for now, I will see later if nobody managed to solve it if I try again).

EDIT
I think this may work well. Also ignored pairs with one single element

```
    var input = ['A','B','C','D','E'];

    function getPairCombinations(arr){
        if(arr.length < 2)
            return [arr];
        else
        {
            var result = [];
            for(var x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
                for(var i = x+1; i < arr.length; i++)
                {
                    var first = [arr[x], arr[i]];
                    var rest = arr.slice();
                    rest.splice(i,1);
                    rest.splice(x,1);
                    var options = [];
                    var restCombinations = getPairCombinations(rest);
                    for(var j in restCombinations)
                    {
                        var option = [first];
                        for(var k in restCombinations[j])
                        {
                            if(restCombinations[j][k][0] && restCombinations[j][k][0].length > 1)
                                option = option.concat(restCombinations[j][k]);
                        }
                        options.push(option);
                    }
                    result.push(options);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    function getAllPairCombinations(arr){
        var result = [];
        var allCombinations = getPairCombinations(arr);

        for(var i in allCombinations)
            for(var j in allCombinations[i])
                result.push(allCombinations[i][j]);

        return result;
    }

    var output = getAllPairCombinations(input);
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below will work specifically for your example. However it will need to be tweaked to handle an input array containing more than 5 elements. Hope this helps get you on the right track. Cheers!

```
var input = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
var pairs = [];
var results = [];

//loop through and generate combinations of pairs
for (var i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
    pairs.push([input[i], input[j]]);
  }
}

//loop through and create arrays consisting of pairs sets
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length - 1; i++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < pairs.length; j++) {
    if(pairs[i].includes(pairs[j][0]) == false && pairs[i].includes(pairs[j][1]) == false)
    {
            results.push([pairs[i], pairs[j]]);
    }
  }
}

//loop through original set of inputs checking for missing element and add to array
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
  {
    if(results[j][0].includes(input[i]) == false && results[j][1].includes(input[i]) == false)
    {
    results[j].push([input[i]]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: For the example it works perfect. But I need that if I pass 3 elements it works, or more than 5 too. It doesn't work correctly, there are repeated cases and sometimes there are still 2 "pairs" of 1 single element each one. 
We must find a way to do that amount of FORs dynamically and not what they are 3. I'm still working to solve it, thanks for your collaboration, it can help.